# Pulling a single matrix out of an Array imported from MATLAB using R.matlab

Tags: arrays, r, matlab, list, matrix

So I have an array of ten 36 x 36 matrices in Matlab. I saved that Array called A as a .mat. I then used the R package R.matlab to import the file. I am trying to find the structural hamming distance of each of the ten matrixes in Array A using the function shd from R package pcalg. For a normal matrix the process to do this is as follows

```
library(pcalg)
library(R.matlab)
testfile = readMat("SingleMatrix.mat")
testfile = as.matrix(testfile$SingleMatrix)
library(igraph)
Test=as.graphnel(graph.adjacency(testfile, weighted = T))
shd(Correct,Test)
```

this gives the structural hamming distance, which is just a number comparing the Correct matrix to the Test matrix.

How can I do this for the list of lists that an Array turns into when imported into R from Matlab? I want the Structural hamming distance for each of the ten matrixes. is there a way to automate pulling them out and turning them into graphnel types then doing the comparison?

The structure of the imported data looks like this:

```
str(testfile)

List of 1
 $ K210000ALARM:List of 10
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:37, 1:37] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:37, 1:37] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:37, 1:37] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:37, 1:37] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:37, 1:37] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:37, 1:37] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:37, 1:37] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:37, 1:37] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:37, 1:37] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:37, 1:37] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "header")=List of 3
  ..$ description: chr "MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Tue Jan 31 06:58:46 2017                                        "
  ..$ version    : chr "5"
  ..$ endian     : chr "little"
```

Answer (score 0):

This code recreates the structure of your data.

```
testfile <- list(lapply(1:10, function(i) list(matrix(i:(8+i), 3))))
```

You should be able to pull out the first matrix with

```
testfile[[1]][[1]][[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

and the second with

```
testfile[[1]][[2]][[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    5    8
[2,]    3    6    9
[3,]    4    7   10
```

**list of matrices**

To flatten the structure into a list of matrices (which might be the best structure for them), you could use

```
myMatList <- lapply(unlist(testfile, recursive=FALSE), function(i) unlist(i))
```

Here, `unlist(testfile, recursive=FALSE)` strips off the outer list of length 1, and `unlist(i)` strips off the inner lists of length 1.

**array**

To get an array, you could use

```
# get array of correct dimensions with 0s
myArray <- array(0, c(dim(testfile[[1]][[2]][[1]]), 10))
# fill it in
for(i in 1:10) myArray[,,i] <- testfile[[1]][[i]][[1]]
```

which returns

```
myArray[,,1:2]
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    5    8
[2,]    3    6    9
[3,]    4    7   10
```

**get distances**

for the list of matrices, The following will probably work.

```
myHamsList <- lapply(myMatList, function(i) shd(Correct,
                                       as.graphnel(graph.adjacency(testfile, weighted = T))))
```